# How can I install sebek?

Tags: kernel

I want to install a sebek client in my Ubuntu which arose so many problem.
First of all, I can't get a sebek client whose version likes 3.2.0b.
It still failed when I got a sebek soruce code because the kernel version of Ubuntu is not 2.6.
Is any one has a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [Sebek project](https://projects.honeynet.org/sebek/) is not developed for more than 7 years.

I am afraid that there is no way to install it to modern versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: I can't agree more! 
I don't need to do this now. Thank you!